# Concatenation php string to javascript string

Tags: javascript, php, string, concatenation

I have some question about concatenation php string to javascript string ...

for example:

php variable

```
$man = "Jamse";
```

and have javascript function

```
<script>
    if (document.getElementById("fname").value == "") {
        q = false;
        msg = <?php echo 'Please fill first name'.$formErrors['fname'].'\n' ?>;
    }
</script>
```

i want to do something like this can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`alert('my name is: <?php echo $man; ?>' );`

Comment: what can i do if i need to exactly concat it ?

Comment: When your page is rendeded, `<?php echo $man; ?>` will be replaced with whatever is in `$man`; in this case the rendered output will be `alert('my name is: Jamse' );`

Comment: @MikeChristensen That is a good point. If `$man` is populated via user input (via form, etc.) you will want to validate your input.

Comment: The question as you have it now should work, assuming `$formErrors` is declared and has valid values.

Comment: Just an aside, you may want to put in a space :) `<?php echo 'Please fill first name '.$formErrors['fname'].'\n' ?>;`

Comment: :D there is something else problem it give me php ERROR but i have not  access to see the error and i did not know what error the php is Trow

Comment: if (document.getElementById("fname").value == "") {
q = false;
msg = "<?php echo 'Please fill first name'.$formErrors['fname'].'\n'; ?>";
}
the correct answer is this :D

Answer (score 1):

```
alert('my name is: <?= $man; ?>');
```

Since PHP will insert `$man` on the server side, it's not a separate string that must be combined by JS. All the browser will see is

```
alert('my name is: Jamse');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not write it all in php?

```
<?php
$man = "Jamse";
echo "<script>
function alertMyName() {
    alert('my name is:" . $man . "');
}
</script>";
?>
```

Comment: @ElGavilan can you elaborate?

Comment: It is better to leave the static parts of the HTML and javascript code in place and only use PHP to render the dynamic parts. Echoing the entire HTML is generally considered bad form as it makes your code harder to maintain and more prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are true, I just forgot to write quotes and javascript did not understand it was a String and gave me an error. The correct code:

```
   if (document.getElementById("fname").value == "") {
        q = false;
        msg = "<?php echo 'Please fill first name'.$formErrors['fname'].'\n'; ?>";
    }
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question? Or posting further info? It's hard to understand the sentence above the code (plus the sentence is part of the code block). If this is indeed an answer, please edit it to be readable. If it's additional info for your question, edit your question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I think he's just agreeing with the other answers, which told him to use quotes.