# Concatenation Unexpected Identifier error PHP

Tags: javascript, php, concatenation, magento-1.9

I'm trying to do some concatenation in Magento 1.x and am getting an "Unexpected Identifier" error, the following code is the snippet, and each of the PHP echos are formatted as:

1. $product->getPrice() - Integer - e.g: `45.00`
2. $product->getName() - String - e.g: `Product Name Here`

```
var testVar = "12345::'" + echo $product->getPrice() + "'::'" + echo $product->Name() + "'::ProductID";
```

I can't figure out why it's not working, can anyone help please?

Comment: What on earth is this code? Is it PHP, or Javascript? Pick one.

Comment: 1) if you're mixing PHP + JS - don't. They execute differently. Just use data-* tags on HTML DOM elements using PHP to echo the value and retrieve in JS. 2) You don't open/close PHP tags so you're echo's are literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var testVar = "12345::'" <?php echo $product->getPrice() ?> "'::'" <?php echo $product->Name()?>  "'::ProductID";
```

refer [Concatenation php string to javascript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563113/concatenation-php-string-to-javascript-string)

Comment: Thanks guys! I missed that